# Guice: Configure singleton without @Singleton or otherwise modifying implementation

Tags: java, binding, singleton, guice

I have a `Service` interface and `ServiceImpl` implementation class in a standalone library that I don't want to have any dependency on Guice.

However I am using Guice in an app which uses `Service`. In this app, I want to bind `Service` to `ServiceImpl`, and I want `ServiceImpl` to be a singleton.

Ordinarily I'd do this by annotating `ServiceImpl` with `@Singleton` and then just binding like so

```
bind(Service.class).to(ServiceImpl.class);
```

But since `ServiceImpl` has no dependency on Guice I can't add the annotation, or otherwise modify its source with anything Guicy.

I can bind `Service` to `ServiceImpl` in the app's module, but it's unclear to me how to configure `ServiceImpl` to be a singleton 'externally' in the app's module (or otherwise).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See: https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Scopes

> Scopes
>
> Guice uses annotations to identify scopes. Specify the scope for a type by applying the scope annotation to the implementation class.
>
> Scopes can also be configured in bind statements:

`bind(Service.class).to(ServiceImpl.class).in(Singleton.class);` should work for you.